# How does the EU decide involvement for conflict prevention, peace and stability for a specific case?

Tags: european-union, foreign-aid, funding

According to [this archived map](https://wayback.archive-it.org/12090/20220823091937/https:/instrument-for-peace-map.ec.europa.eu/) the EU is and has been involved in many projects under the Service for Foreign Policy Instruments (FPI) umbrella.

A fraction of these projects are related to [Conflict prevention, peace and stability](https://fpi.ec.europa.eu/what-we-do/conflict-prevention-peace-and-stability_en) and they can be easily listed using [this resource](https://fpi.ec.europa.eu/fpi-projects_en?f%5B0%5D=fpi_topic_vocabulary_topic%3A63).

[This page](https://fpi.ec.europa.eu/what-we-do/conflict-prevention-peace-and-stability_en) explains how conflict prevention, peace and stability projects work in more detail:

> The EU has financed more than 1,000 crisis response and conflict
> prevention projects carried out worldwide over the past 10 years. They
> helped to alleviate tensions, prevent conflict through mediation,
> broker and implement peace agreements, reintegrate persons involved in
> conflict into society, and ensure transitional justice and
> accountability.

However, it does not seem to include details about initiating such projects. How does the EU decide if a case should be considered and how much funding is required?